# Regex for cryptocurrencies

Tags: regex

I want to validate some fraction of cryptocurrencies, for example, I have the following VALID values

```
0,000001
0,000000001
1,00
1.000,00
```

Right now I have this regex for validating currency (yes, with comma instead of dot)

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$/
```

How can I do the same for the values above?

Comment: Just replace the last {2} with a + or {2,} optionally followed by the same thing you did at the very front where you expec true first and last thing to be non zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might either match the more exact pattern starting with a digit 1-9, or match a pattern starting with a zero and have 1 or more digits after the comma:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}|0\d*,\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZfwNiA/1)